# Only match URL beginning with 'www' or 'http(s)://' and nothing else

Tags: regex

I am using a **Regular Expression** pattern for my blog site to make URL addresses as *clickable links*, what works great. The pattern has this format:

```
/(href=")?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)?)/
```

### So what's the problem?

But in the near past I found that this pattern also *matches filenames* so when the user post some filename in the comment, system will make it as link. You can see this effect here:

[image]

### And what I am trying to achieve?

What I am trying to achieve is match every of these URL formats except the last one example (see image below), so `mysite.com` or `filename.php` won't be highlighted.

[image]

---

**Inputs what should be matched:**

```
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|         Example          |                     Explanation                      |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| http(s)://www.mysite.com | because it starts with http(s):// and has URL format |
| www.mysite.com           | because it starts with www. and has URL format       |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Inputs what shouldn't be matched:**

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|      Example      |                    Explanation                   |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| mysite.com        | because it doesn't start with http(s):// or www. |
|                   | even it has URL format                           |
| http(s)://mytext  | because it doesn't have URL format               |
| http://localhost/ | because it doesn't have URL format               |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

**How *URL format* looks like?**

For this case, we can specify URL format by this pattern:

```
([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)?))
```

Examples:

```
google.com, google.co.uk, accounts.google.com, google.com/somepath/ ...
```

### Conclusion

A tried adding `www\.` string into this pattern, but no matches found then. So how can I edit this regex to *match URLs beginning with 'www' or 'http(s)://' and nothing else*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with defining what is real url and what is not. You can read the sentence and understand the meaning - that's something computers are not capable of. With parsing text, you always either miss some data or have false-positives.

Comment: Quote: "*But I don't want to limit it only for urls starting with `http://` or `https://`*". Please make up your mind.

Comment: You **still** didn't exactly specify **what is a valid URL in your opinion**. I tried to push you in the correct direction but - do you actually read my comments?

Comment: I added examples of inputs and explanations why they should or shouldn't be matched.

Comment: No idea why this got -3 downvotes if it's so detailed and got high quaility screenshots. Isn't this the purpose of stackoverflow so people can come here and read old questions like a tutorial?

Comment: @SSpoke it was downvoted before my edits, so this is the reason why I have so downvotes.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Ah I see, still was pretty detailed I checked out your initial post and I haven't seen anything wrong with it, I guess people just like to see colors and pictures otherwise they are not happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regexp is definitelly not perfect but [will do what you want](http://regex101.com/r/sC5wV5/1):

```
(http[s]?:\/\/|www.|ftp:\/\/){1,2}([-a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)?)
```

It can be tricked to match non-urls, but this can't be abused. Increasing smartness greatly increases complexity.